# Can not choose Japanese keyboard in some apps

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard

everybody!

I've been struggling with fixing one issue in one of the apps that we are working on for the whole week now and I didn't get any idea of the reasons and possible solution. Could you please help me out - maybe some of you encountered the same problem:

Initially the issue has been reported in just one project, but then I also tried to reproduce it in other apps - in some of the apps the same problems was present, in some everything worked properly.

**So the problem:**

1. open the app
2. select any text field
3. try to select Japanese keyboard (keeping in mind that the
   language has been already added in the settings of the iPhone)

**Actual Result:** Japanese keyboard is not being displayed in the list of available keyboards in the app

**Expected Result:** Japanese keyboard should be available in the list of available keyboards and user should be able to input text in the text field in Japanese

I would really appreciate if somebody could share some additional insights. Or maybe ways you fixed it in case you came across a similar issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the Japanese keyboard through the Settings app under General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards?

Comment: Yes, i can choose Japanese keyboard in another apps but not in this.

Comment: I'm not asking about other apps. Has the keyboard been added in the Settings app under General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards?

Comment: yes, keyboard has been added.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the text field's keyboard type.

Make sure the keyboard type is `default` or another, appropriate, non-ASCII-compatible type.

```
textField.keyboardType = .default
```

The keyboard type for a text field or view can also be configured in Interface Builder.

See also:

- the [keyboard type property for `UITextInputTraits`-conforming classes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624457-keyboardtype)
- [all available keyboard types](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uikeyboardtype).

Comment: The mostly of text inputs in app have default keyboard type, but keyboard still do not working properly.

Comment: Yes. The problem was in NSString extension.